# Proper way to reset a flex scanner between files

Tags: c, lex, flex-lexer

I am using a flex scanner to scan a bunch of files. I currently loop over the files and call `yylex()` but it seems like the states within flex are not resetting. Is the proper thing to do to set a function to call on `<EOF>` to reset any variables, and `BEGIN INITIAL` before the next call to `yylex()`?

When testing this, it seems like this sends me into an infinite loop because I end up going back to INITIAL with no more matches in the file, so it never exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example of using an `<EOF>` match to switch buffers in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html); it uses the following code:

```
<<EOF>> {
             if ( --include_stack_ptr  0 )
                 {
                 yyterminate();
                 }

             else
                 {
                 yy_delete_buffer( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER );
                 yy_switch_to_buffer(
                      include_stack[include_stack_ptr] );
                 }
         }
```

You would want to add `BEGIN(INITIAL)` to the `else` branch, since `yy_switch_to_buffer` does not reset the start condition.

Comment: I saw that after I posted the question. I guess within this I should also reset any of my 'global' variables I am using within the scanner for that particular buffer, huh?

Comment: @Derek, If you need them to be reset, you should reset them. I don't think there is any way that flex can know that your global variables even exist, much less what their values should be :)

Comment: A bit of a side-topic..but is that a typcial way people use flex? Setting some global vars that are modified depending on a state? Thats typically what I have been doing..but at the end of the file I'm ready to reset all those vars and start on the next file

Comment: @Derek, These days, you could use a reentrant scanner, which allows you to provide a user-defined "extra" structure to contain persistent variables for the scanner. The reentrant scanner API includes `yy_init` and `yy_destroy` which set up and tear down the scanner's own persistent state; you would wrap those in functions which set up and tear down your persistent state. It's cleaner, and also re-entrant. And you can have multiple scanners running in parallel. I'd recommend moving towards that model.